# Simple orm mapper for .net

Tags: c#, sql, orm

what would be best ORM sql mapper for .net only for quering data where tables don't have primary keys and sometimes all fields in table are nullable ?

Comment: "Best" is subjective, and recommendations for finding a tool have long been off-topic here.  Sorry...

Comment: as @DavidStratton, this will be nothing but subjection preferences. Entity Framework is my favorite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper can be an option for you https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net

Comment: Would definitely recommend it.